# Problems with Filtering DataView & Display Back to Original Datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, filter, dataview

I have a MySQL database with comments, and I've already filled in my `dataGridView_flaggedComments` with flagged comments using this function:

```
private void button_Search1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    commentCount = 0;
    //comboBox_stockIndex.SelectedIndex = 0;
    richTextBox_flaggedComments.Clear();
    dataGridView_flaggedComments.Refresh();
    DataTable flaggedcomments = new DataTable("flaggedcomments");
    using (MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(strProvider))
    {
        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Comment_ID, Comments_Date, Author, Title, Comments_Comment, Tickers_Ticker_ID FROM comments ORDER BY Comments_Date ASC", sqlConn))
        {
            da.Fill(flaggedcomments);
        }
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(sourceDirTemp + comboBox_crimeKeywords.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt");
    var query = flaggedcomments.AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
words.Any(wordOrPhrase => Regex.IsMatch(r.Field<string>("Comments_Comment"), @"\b" + Regex.Escape(wordOrPhrase) + @"\b",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));

    dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource = query.AsDataView();
}
```

The flagged comments appear in `dataGridView_flaggedComments` are belong to different stock prices (each stock has its unique symbol and its Ticker_ID). I am trying to filter the current `dataGridView_flaggedComments` so that it only shows what I selected from `comboBox_stockIndex`.

However, my code will somehow retrieve all comments for this particular symbol from database rather than filtering what's in the `dataGridView_flaggedComments`. Can anyone point out what went wrong?

I've went through quite a number of questions at SO, but couldn't really relate it. Here's my code and it would be much appreciated if I could get some help! Thank you!

```
private void comboBox_stockIndex_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable link_stockIndex = new DataTable("link_stockIndex");
    using (MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(strProvider))
    {
        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Ticker_ID, Symbol FROM tickers", sqlConn))
        {
            da.Fill(link_stockIndex);
        }
    }
    foreach (DataRow da in link_stockIndex.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows[i].Cells["Tickers_Ticker_ID"].Value.ToString() != "" && comboBox_stockIndex.SelectedItem.ToString() == da["Symbol"].ToString())
            {
                (dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource as DataView).RowFilter = string.Format("Tickers_Ticker_ID = '{0}'", da["Ticker_ID"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a very strange code in your `comboBox_stockIndex_SelectedIndexChanged` handler.

Just have a look: on every index change of combobox you're quering database with **always the same** query and later in the code you actually doesn't use results of this query. What for is it?

Let's go further. You are iterating over your `dataGridView_flaggedComments` rows and setting your `RowFilter` multiple times. Looks pretty unnecessary, as only the last filter will take place.

It looks like your code should be something like this:

1. Query database for `SELECT Ticker_ID, Symbol FROM tickers` as you have made, but **outside** SelectedIndexChanged handler, and store it into datatable.
2. In `SelectedIndexChanged` handler iterate over that datatable, and find a row having "Symbol" equal to your `comboBox_stockIndex.SelectedItem`.
3. Set `RowFilter` like "Tickers_Ticker_ID = Ticker_ID from row you've found in previous point. And return, don't set multiple filters.

Remark: I don't know how frequently your `tickers` database table being changed, so maybe suggestion about query it outside of `SelectedIndexChanged` is wrong if it changes very frequently.

Comment: Hi Andy, I am looking into your explanation. `tickers` database won't change at all, it will remain the same throughout the whole process.

Comment: Ok, that means my suggestion what you should not query this table each time your combobox selected index has changed was right.

Comment: Hi Andy, do you mind looking at https://pastebin.com/b9jq3wHn ? Even when I already simplified the `comboBox_stockIndex_SelectedIndexChanged`, the code still doesn't work, it will still show all the comments for Tickers_Ticker_ID = 1 rather than just from the flagged comments from `dataGridView_flaggedComments`. Something is wrong with the `DataView` or `DataGridView` binding?

Comment: @Shyuan, here is string of code from your exmple at pastebin: `dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Tickers_Ticker_ID = '1'");` So you are explicitly setting filter for Tickers_Ticker_ID = 1. Why do you expecting another result being shown? ;)

Comment: Hi Andy, in pastebin I explicitly set the filter to `Tickers_Ticker_ID = 1` because I want to show you that the problem is not at the `Tickers_Ticker_ID = 1`, but somewhere else, since this filter is bringing up all the Ticker_ID 1 comments rather than the flagged comments for Ticker_ID 1. There's a problem at DataView part, but I couldn't sort it out. I've started a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706066/dataview-rowfilter-doesnt-filter-the-rows-on-datagridview/26712965?iemail=1&noredirect=1#26712965) & indeed someone is saying about the DataView, I need time to understand.