# DataView RowFilter doesn't filter the Rows on DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dataview, rowfilter

I have this function `button_Search1_Click` to search for comments that match keywords, then display these flagged comments in `dataGridView_flaggedComments`.

Next, if there's any changes on the `comboBox_stockIndex`, I want the filter to take place i.e. filter the flagged comments in `dataGridView_flaggedComments` with the `Tickers_Ticker_ID` of `1`. But when I do that, all the comments (regardless flagged or not) belong to `Tickers_Ticker_ID` of `1` display on my `dataGridView_flaggedComments`. It should have only display the flagged comments for `Tickers_Ticker_ID` of `1`, not all the comments.

I think there's something wrong with the `DataSource` but I couldn't figure it out. Any help would be very very much appreciated! Thank you!

(If I did miss any similar questions, kindly point it out. Thank you very much!)

```
private void button_Search1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    commentCount = 0;
    richTextBox_flaggedComments.Clear();
    dataGridView_flaggedComments.Refresh();
    DataTable flaggedcomments = new DataTable("flaggedcomments");
    using (MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(strProvider))
    {
        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(
        "SELECT Comment_ID, Comments_Date, Author, Title, Comments_Comment, " + 
              " Tickers_Ticker_ID FROM comments ORDER BY Comments_Date ASC", sqlConn))
        {
            da.Fill(flaggedcomments);
        }
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(sourceDirTemp + 
                          comboBox_crimeKeywords.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt");
    var query = flaggedcomments.AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
        words.Any(wordOrPhrase => Regex.IsMatch(r.Field<string>("Comments_Comment"),
              @"\b" + Regex.Escape(wordOrPhrase) + @"\b",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));

    dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource = query.AsDataView();
}


private void comboBox_stockIndex_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource as DataView;
    if (dv == null)
        throw new Exception("Bad Data Source type");
    else
    {
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Tickers_Ticker_ID = '1'");
        dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource = dv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DataView` as such does not **hold** any data.

When you set the filter you are effectively replacing the orginal filter in your `LinqDataView`, that is the `Where` clause, by the new filter, that is by the `RowFilter`.

You need to concatenate them to create a double condition.

Since your `Where` clause uses a complex `RegEx` I think the easiest way will be to re-use it, appending it with the new, simple `'Tickers_Ticker_ID = ' + id` condition.

If you don't want to reapply the original filter you may want to store the filtered rows in a temporary Table. Here I have a DataSet DS and first clone the structure of the 1st Table, name the new Table and add it to the DataSet. When appropriate I copy the filtered rows over from the query:

Set up the Temp Table, where you set up you other DB stuff:

```
DataSet DS;                             // if you don't already have one..
                                        // put it at class level!

DS = new DataSet();                     // ..create it
DataTable DT = DS.Tables[0].Clone();    // the temp table has the sdame structure
DT.TableName = "temp";                  // is called by a name
DS.Tables.Add(DT);                      // and (optionally) added to the DataSet.
```

When you do the search you load the data into the temp table:

```
DS.Tables["temp"].Rows.Clear();
query.CopyToDataTable( DS.Tables["temp"], LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
DGV.DataSource = DS.Tables["temp"];
```

Now you can use it in the `combo_filter_SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
 string id = ddl_filter.Text;
 if (id == "") DGV.DataSource = DS.Tables["temp"];
 else
 {
    DataView dv = new DataView(DS.Tables["temp"])
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("id = " + id) ;
    DGV.DataSource = dv;
 }
```

Comment: Hi TaW, I used to do like what you said i.e. reuse it. But I do not want it to sort of like repeating the same thing, hence I'm trying to "clean up" the code. Is there no way to fix my code? E.g. rather than using `DataView` which hold no data, maybe I can use something else so that it will hold/remember the current represented data on DGV? Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Well either you do some filtering in the code repeatedly or you keep the filtered data in a tempoary storage. A DataTable is a rather obvious storage choice imo, see the updated answer..

Comment: Hi TaW, thank you for the guide, my question could be silly, should I put the first part of your code to `button_Search1_Click` or in a new class? If I put under `button_Search1_Click`, then I couldn't access the `DS` in `combo_filter_SelectedIndexChanged` from `button_Search1_Click`, right? Besides, is `DataSet DS = new DataSet();` missing from the code? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, you are right, the 1st part of the code really is two parts: 1.1: The setup of the temp table, with name and structure. This should probably go where you set up your other DB stuff, including the DataSet, if you use one. Yes, I left out the creation, since I has assumed you had it already somewhere. (Not necessary, just a handy collection of Tables), the other part (1.2) will go where you process the search, probably the button click. - I have added these hints to the answer as well..

Comment: Hi TaW, when I put the code in `combo_filter_SelectedIndexChanged`, the `if (id == "") DGV.DataSource = DS.Tables["temp"];` line shows `DS is not in the current context`. I wonder how can I access the `DS` in the search function? Sorry as I only do this for part of my project and programming really makes me lost. Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Move the DataSet to class level! (Which is why I had inserted an empty line)

Comment: I see, that helps :) I am testing on the code now :) sorry for the late!

Comment: Any idea why `Cannot find Table 0` error appears on this line `DataTable DT = DS.Tables[0].Clone();`?

Comment: Well surely because there is no Table in the DataSet yet, when you reach that line. You need to use the Table you have to create a Clone; if it isn't in the DS simply use it as you have is: `DataTable DT = yourTable.Clone();` I think it was `flaggedcomments`. This is only defined locally as well btw; you may need to move it to call level as well..

Comment: Hi TaW, thank you very much for your guides and hints!! It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Your filtering wrong... try this instead...

```
  dv.RowFilter = "Tickers_Ticker_ID = 1";
```

Comment: Then set a breakpoint on where you set the Dataview and make sure it is something...